How does one implement a callable class with a single own method?
Explanation of the idea :
I would like to build a class that can be called like a function without initializing it as an instance. For example, I want to create a class named logger and use it in two ways: the first way is logger("some text") and the second way is logger.info("some text"), using dot notation.
Problems :
The issues I am facing are that I do not want to create a method inside the class that represents the first way, because this method will appear during dot notation. For example:
class logger {

  // if i want it to represents the first way: logger("some text")
  // this will appear if i write logger.log, and i don't want that.
  static log(){}

  // this method what i want it to be accessible in object pattern.
  // example: logger.info()
  static info(){}

}

There is another problem as well:
When I try to access the logger class, it shows me other methods and properties. I want only the methods and properties that I have defined to appear in dot notation. If I, for instance, write logger., it will show me apply and call and bind.
One last thing:
I would like to implement the idea using TypeScript.


The use case you're presenting with every of its conditions/requirements and its usage already cancels out the implementation as a class. It's not that you just don't need it. By description and usage a class implementation just would by utterly wrong. What you need is a plain logger function with two methods nailed to it (functions are objects too).

Quoting my above comment ...

The use case [the OP is] presenting with every of its conditions/requirements and its usage already cancels out the implementation as a class. It's not that [one] just [does not] need it. By description and usage a class implementation just would by utterly wrong. What one need [s] is a plain logger function with [an additional single method] nailed to it (functions are objects too).

The simple reason why using a class is the wrong approach is that class constructors have to be invoked always with new, a simple invocation, like the OP is seeking for with the described use case, will immediately throw a TypeError.
A running JS implementation which does exactly what the OP is looking for might look similar to and as straightforward as the following provided code ...


// -- begin of logger module scope. --

function loggerInfo(text) {
  console.info({ loggerInfo, text });
}
function logger(text) {
  console.log({ logger, text });
}

// - let `loggerInfo` be the `logger`'s
//   enumerable, non configurable, non
//   writable `info` property/method.

Reflect.defineProperty(logger, 'info', {
  enumerable: true,
  value: loggerInfo,
});

// export default logger;

// -- end of logger module scope. --


// another script block or module scope.

logger('directly invoked logger.');
logger.info('logger\'s `info` method invoked.');
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }



The above code as valid, tanspiling/compiling and running TS code can be found at this TS playground.
And regarding following of the OP's non problem ...

there's also another problem:
When I try to access the logger class, it shows me other methods and properties. I want only the methods and properties that I have defined to appear in dot notation. if i write logger., it will show me apply and call and bind

This is not a problem, neither of the logger approach/implementation nor of the language itself; it's just how your IDE works.
A class does manifest itself in a constructor function, thus if you access a class you actually access a special function, and functions have methods too. Every function inherits call, apply and bind from Function.prototype. Thus these methods are never owned by a function itself, hence they will not show up as own or own enumerable properties. Your IDE is just clever enough to recognize the inheritance/prototype chain and show these methods as available properties.

thanks for your answer and you time, please check the edit in my question above.

The IIFE based solution mainly suffers from the same misconception, trying to make a class somehow callable which will never work. And which techniques and how they are applied within the IIFE towards this goal leave me already puzzled. Always try the most simple approach first, preferably in plain JS. Don't be tempted by what TS seems to offer. This stuff can not do anything magic beyond the limits of JS. My above approach and implementation with the final solution being converted last to TS does just prove that.

I just want to tell you the IIFE solution work with me, and i made the class callable and the same time has methods, i just have problem with change the logValue variable, and also i would to remove/hide the function.prototype, when we defined a object then these prototype will be hide, so i want to hide it like object.

@Weelpert ... 1/4 ... "i made the class callable" ... No, you did not. What you're doing in reality is abusing a class constructor function twice as carrier for 3 methods.
There is so much wrong with the entire code. But I frankly need to say, you have not the slightest clue about the basics, neither in JS nor in TS. It's merely luck that the code does not break.
But why does it actually work?

@Weelpert ... 2/4 ... At first you make the LoggerLogic class constructor the new prototype of the MakeLoggerCallable function. Then by assigning the class to the same function you copy over the class' 3 methods from the class constructor function to the MakeLoggerCallable function. By returning the latter you end up logger having assigned the IIFE's MakeLoggerCallable function to it. Now you know why logger is callable. It's a function. More interesting is, MakeLoggerCallable just forwards to the IIFE's locally scoped logger function.

@Weelpert ... 3/4 ... Thus making the introduction of MakeLoggerCallable superfluous/needless/a waste. Regardless of whether returning MakeLoggerCallable or directly logger from the IIFE, you always end up having a function, nothing close to a class, nothing that is ever going to be instantiated. Why should such a function have linked another prototype to it, than its default one? It just does not make any sense.

@Weelpert ... 4/4 ... If one wants the logger function to carry methods, one should assign them directly. But not as you did through Object.assign(MakeLoggerCallable, LoggerLogic) with a class constructor function ab/used as object. With everything said and hopefully clarified, if you're now going to refactor your code, your solution in its basic structure will look exactly like the implementation of my above posted answer.

@Weelpert ... And since you are already within a module, the usage of an IIFE like you did with ... export const logger = (() => { ... })() ... is not necessary at all.

Thank you very much! Your explanation was extremely clear and helpful. Honestly, I have seen several projects that use classes without writing a constructor, and some projects don't even initialize the instance of the class. They simply use it as a container to group methods and properties.

@Weelpert ... "They simply use it as a container to group methods and properties" ... out of interest, do you mind providing the background of developers who are doing such stuff. What's theirs first / second language?

@Weelpert ... And since all the explanation/s were so much of help, you also might consider to mark my answer as "accepted".
